# Search varchar2 for a format?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-like

How do you query varchar2 for a format? Example is Varchar2 field containing date as mm/dd/yyyy '01/01/2015'.  How would I find a date that was written as yyyy/mm/dd '2015/01/01' as I do not know the incorrectly formatted date so i can't literally search it.  I just want to write `where FIELD_1 like '####/##/##'` but that obviously does not work.

Answer (score 3):

Of course what you want to do works, if you use regular expressions:

```
where regexp_like(field_1, '^[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}$')
```

As a side note: you should not be storing dates in the database as strings.  You should be using dates instead.

Comment: Trust me I know better, not my DB.   It's actually a vendor datatabse...It's a crazy world out there!

Answer (score 1):

Gordon's answer is probably good enough for what you need, but it may be an issue that the regular expression he gave you will match things like 9999/99/99 that are not dates.

If you really need to match dates -- and if the date is the entire value of the VARCHAR2 and not just embedded somewhere in it -- then a function can help.

In the below example, I create a function called `safe_to_date` that returns a NULL if the given VARCHAR2 value is not a date in the specified format.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION safe_to_date ( p_string VARCHAR2 ) RETURN DATE IS
BEGIN
  RETURN to_date(p_string,'YYYY/MM/DD');
EXCEPTION
  WHEN others THEN
    RETURN NULL;
END;


with my_table AS 
 ( SELECT '9999/99/99' /*invalid*/ my_column FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT '2015/12/25' from dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 'not a date at all' /*invalid*/ FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT '11-NOV-1917' from dual UNION ALL
   SELECT '2015*DEC*25' from dual UNION ALL
   SELECT '2015/02/28' from dual UNION ALL
   SELECT '2015/02/29' /*invalid*/ from dual)
SELECT *
FROM   my_table
WHERE  safe_to_date(my_column) IS NOT NULL;
```

Expected results:

```
25-DEC-2015
11-NOV-1917
25-DEC-2015
28-FEB-2015
```